# Is there any point in completing the formulario 250 when flying to Bolivia?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, bolivia

I flew from Buenos Aires EZE to Bolivia (Santa Cruz de la Sierra VVI layover, then La Paz LPB final destination) and during the flight (Boliviana De Aviacion flight 709 + Boliviana De Aviacion flight 681) I was asked by one of the flight attendants to complete formulario 250, which eventually nobody looked at.

Is there any point in completing the formulario 250 when flying to Bolivia?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thanks you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111566/whats-the-point-of-hand-filled-immigration-forms?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.3623

Comment: This is a seriously flawed question. The premise is based on the experience of one individual on one occasion. Even the one answer admits that it's little more than guesswork.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass what's the flaw in the question itself? My related experience only motivates why I'm asking the question. Sample size = 1 doesn't prevent me from asking the question, on the contrary.

Comment: @Franck I explained the flaw in my comment. Your phraseology is clearly asking 'I filled this form in but nobody looked at it. Why bother?'. Based on one occurrence the question is flawed. If your question is really 'Why does the Bolivian Government ask for this data?' then you should have asked that,

Comment: @Arthur'sPass I don't see how it makes the question flawed as if the single occurrence doesn't reflect the typical case then simply state it so in an answer

Comment: Good question, why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is thin ice for an Answer, but I'll bet the reality is:

a) The Bolivian government issued this form to be completed by those entering the country;

b) The Bolivian government makes airlines distribute the forms to incoming passengers; and

c) Sometimes, maybe even most of the time, a Bolivian officer will demand the completed form on arrival.