# When I come back, why does Canada ask when I left the country?

Tags: canada, borders, canadian-residents

I've recently read that Canada implemented the Entry/Exit Initiative, so the border agency has been collecting information via airline manifests (lists of passenger names with their date of births, passport data, etc.) on who left the country. However, when I return to Canada, I always have to fill out the declaration form which asks me for the date of my departure from Canada.

I'm wondering then, why do they still care to ask?
For a counterexample, I never have to answer this question in the EU.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111566/whats-the-point-of-hand-filled-immigration-forms. UK and US got rid of these forms 2+ years ago, Canada's just behind the times.

Comment: Paper declarations are becoming rare, if still used at all, in Canada as well, at least for major airports. I have not needed to fill them in the past few years flying to YYZ, YUL, YYC, YEG, YVR.

Comment: But you might not have left the country by air.

Comment: @user102008, Canada also gets entry data from the CBP to use as records of land and ferry exits to the US, so there really aren't many exits of any sort they won't have data for.

Comment: @xngtng Really? There are machine kiosks on arrival, they prompt one to scan the declaration form after scanning the passport.

Comment: @user102008 If one leaves by land then the information is definitely transmitted by the US to Canada and vice versa.

Comment: @sequence The new kiosks I've seen include on-screen declaration instead of the paper form at YVR, YUL and YEG at least. All next-gen Primary Inspection Kiosks should have that ability (but of course for operational  reasons they may change it from time to time): https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/services/border-tech-frontiere/how-comment-eng.html.

Comment: @xngtng But, I mean, the kiosks still ask you for the same information, i.e. including the data of departure from Canada, as on the paper form, which makes no difference anyway.

Answer (score 9):

There are several reasons why they ask: the most relevant is that when the form was designed, they either didn't have that information any other way, or didn't have it an easy way the officer could see while talking to you.

Of course, the form contains all kinds of information they could look up. For example, it asks for your flight information, even though you've provided your name so it could be looked up. Today's date, even though it's, you know, today.

The forms are becoming obsolete, so redesigning them to ask for less and less information is not going to happen.